# How do I make Padding Non-Transparent?

Tags: html, css, padding, opacity

I want to make the padding Opaque, but opacity isn't working.

```
body {
background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/apKZRmj.png);
font-family:Helvetica;
color:lightgrey;
font-size: 16px;
align:center;
padding: 20px 0;
}
```

Why won't this work?

Comment: The background will go under the padding, that's how it works.  Otherwise you want a margin.  As a sidenote - `align:center` isn't correct...

Comment: I agree to @davidpauljunior, what do you want to do in align:center?, trying to center the text? or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to [W3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)

The padding clears an area around the content (inside the border) of an element. The padding is affected by the background color of the element.

so basically it has no color property to make it an opaque or adding some opacity, I think what you need is 'border'
ex.

```
border: 20px solid #000;
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bJ2CF/2/

Comment: I have the border, but I want it around the entire thing like padding

Comment: what do you mean about 'around the entire object'? do you mean the whole webpage?

Comment: sorry, it's for a tumblr post. I mean so that the entire border is filled in.

Comment: do you mean like this? [http://jsfiddle.net/bJ2CF/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/bJ2CF/2/)

Comment: where it would be like the padding, only around a certain area but instead of a border it would be a black square. it would be like this http://jsfiddle.net/bJ2CF/5/, but i couldn't do it with div, i would need it in the `<style>` section

Comment: im sorry but I think im getting you wrong, are you saying you need the  css style inside the <style></style> tags? like this? [http://jsfiddle.net/bJ2CF/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/bJ2CF/6/)

Answer (score 0):

use background color ,  The padding clears an area around the content